# Pandas breaking column into a matrix by count

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have this column in a df:

```
Column A
--------
x-y: 1
x-y: 2
x-y: 2
x-x: 1
y-x: 2
y-y: 3
y-y: 3
```

Is it possible to break them into a matrix like this?

```
     1     2     3      *based on the range of number of column A
     --------------
x-x  1     0     0      because there's 1 'x-x: 1'
x-y  1     2     0      because there's 1 'x-y: 1' and 2 'x-y: 2'
y-x  0     1     0      because there's 1 'x-y: 2'
y-y  0     0     2      because there's 2 'y-y: 3'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), then get counts by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df)
     Column A
x-y         1
x-y         2
x-y         2
x-x         1
y-x         2
y-y         3
y-y         3

print (df.reset_index())
  index  Column A
0   x-y         1
1   x-y         2
2   x-y         2
3   x-x         1
4   y-x         2
5   y-y         3
6   y-y         3

df = df.reset_index().groupby(['index','Column A']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
Column A  1  2  3
index            
x-x       1  0  0
x-y       1  2  0
y-x       0  1  0
y-y       0  0  2
```

Another solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.index, df['Column A'])
print (df)
Column A  1  2  3
row_0            
x-x       1  0  0
x-y       1  2  0
y-x       0  1  0
y-y       0  0  2
```

---

If is necessary split:

```
print (df)
  Column A
0   x-y: 1
1   x-y: 2
2   x-y: 2
3   x-x: 1
4   y-x: 2
5   y-y: 3
6   y-y: 3

df[['a','b']] = df['Column A'].str.split(':\s+', expand=True)
print (df)

  Column A    a  b
0   x-y: 1  x-y  1
1   x-y: 2  x-y  2
2   x-y: 2  x-y  2
3   x-x: 1  x-x  1
4   y-x: 2  y-x  2
5   y-y: 3  y-y  3
6   y-y: 3  y-y  3

df = df.groupby(['a','b']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
b    1  2  3
a           
x-x  1  0  0
x-y  1  2  0
y-x  0  1  0
y-y  0  0  2
```